# unix skip-header bash function

Tags: bash

Somewhere on stackoverflow I got a bash function called "body" which would echo the header (first line) of a file, and pass the body (rest of the lines) along to stdout. This has been very useful for me to work with files that have headers.

Example:

file.csv:

```
field1,field2
a,2
b,1
```

Commands:

```
$ sort -k2,2 -nr file.csv -t,
a,2
b,1
field1,field2

$ cat file.csv | body sort -nr -t, -k2,2
field1,field2
a,2
b,1
```

Not a great example, but it shows the header staying on top.

Minutes of Googling and searching stackoverflow have revealed nothing.

Can anyone find or reconstruct such a function?

Comment: LOL. "Minutes of googling..."  Microwave society much? :)

Comment: what is "the header of the file"?  That means a lot of different things depending on the file type.  Maybe you want the `head` program, which outputs the first lines of a file?

Comment: Do you have link of that **Somewhere on stackoverflow**?

Comment: @evilotto: Yes, the header is the first line.  No, I don't want head.  If I knew exactly what I wanted, I'd just write it.  I picked up a magic and happy script that echoed the first line (maybe to stderr?) and then passed the rest along (probably to stdout).  It is here on stackoverflow somewhere.  Since it just worked for me, I forgot how it worked.

Comment: @anubhava If I had the link, I never would've asked this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@summea found the answer I was seeking: the body function of Bash from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11856/sort-but-keep-header-line-in-the-at-the-top):

```
# print the header (the first line of input)
# and then run the specified command on the body (the rest of the input)
# use it in a pipeline, e.g. ps | body grep somepattern
body() {
    IFS= read -r header
    printf '%s\n' "$header"
    "$@"
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Here is one way that would allow you to grab the header... and then grab the rest of the csv file, and sort (or whatever else you want to do with the data,) and it all gets saved to the `outpipe`.

```
head -1 file.csv > outpipe | tail -n+2 file.csv | sort >> outpipe
```

**Edit:**

If that approach doesn't work for you, you could always try something like the answers in [this previous discussion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11856/sort-but-keep-header-line-in-the-at-the-top).

Comment: Are you not allowed to use `tail`?

Comment: I tried to clarify above: I don't just need tail.  It separates the first line and the rest, submits the rest to the pipeline, gathers the first line and the rest together for output.

Comment: Maybe [something like this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11856/sort-but-keep-header-line-in-the-at-the-top) could point you in the right direction, if you aren't wanting to use `tail`, here.

Comment: That's it!  Awesome!  It was on stackexchange, not stackoverflow.  If you submit this as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Edited to include that earlier discussion.  I still think chaining `tail`s might be another way to do this... if you add in the `sort`, etc.  But, glad that the other approaches work for you.

Comment: Just a caution note that body function created sub-processes of its own so using it as a pipe with ps command will give you extra output.

Comment: I repeat, if you submit the link to that question, I will accept it as the answer.  I don't know how to use your tail example above to do any of their examples.  For example: "ps -o pid,comm | body grep less"

Answer (score 2):

The basis would be just to reconstruct the out.file from file:

```
(head -n1 file; tail -n+2 file) > out.file
```

You would operate somehow on the second part:

```
(head -n1 file; tail -n+2 file | voodoo -zack -peng) > out.file
```

Comment: That's brilliant. I had no idea you could group the output of two commands like that.  Thanks!